# Custom form validation using jquery plugin, based on attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using Jquery [valdiation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) for validating the form at client side. But I want to do the validation like.

```
<input type="text" id="txtInf" regex="/some regular expression/" error="Inf is mandatory"></inf>
```

here **regex** and **error** are custom attributes. Field will be validated against the given regular expression in regex and if the regular expression text fails then error meessage should be shown.

I tried to add a method to **validator** like this.

```
 $("*[regex]").each(function () {

            $.validator.addMethod($(this).attr('id'), function () {
                return this.optional($(this)) || $(this).attr('regex').test($(this).text());
            }, $(this).attr('error'));

});
```

But there is some issue, with the approach. Please let me know, if I am thinking it right.
If there is some other approach in your mind, please let me know. Any thought process is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that plugin, but it looks like you'll get an error from the use of test().

```
$(this).attr('regex').test($(this).text());
```

should be

```
var regEx = new RegExp($(this).attr('regex'));
regEx.test($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

custom form validation in bootstrap is possible using few lines of code

// Add below code in html

```
  <form id="addForm" action=" " method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate> </form>
```

//  add this in script tag

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            document.getElementById("btn_inject").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                //form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {

                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');

            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
})
();
```

//you will also need this to make the text boxes back to dismiss the validation

```
 $("#Modalidname").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
                $("#Formidname").removeClass('was-validated');

            });
```